# Call non-exported method from static library

Tags: objective-c, c, static-libraries, reverse-engineering

I am using a static library built by someone else in my Objective-C project. There is a C method in the library that I want to call, but it is not exported. How can a call this method from Objective-C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Why do you need that? Obviously the author of that framework did not see any need for this and things can break, if a method is executed directly.

However: Write a category on the receiver with that method and just do it. Objective-C binds dynamically, so this works.

```
@interface FrameworkClass(InternalMethodAddition)
- (void)internalMethod;
@end
// Do not implement this category.
…
FrameworkClass *object = …
[object internalMethod];
```

Comment: Thanks Amin. How would you do this for a static global method? The method would normally just be invoked like: `foo()`.

Comment: This is no method, but a function. It does not work for functions, because the identifiers are not available at runtime and function calls are bound statically.